# How to customize a folder's icon via Python?

Tags: python, windows, desktop.ini

As [this SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/410091/35237) notes, in order to change a folder's icon, one has to change a folder's attribute to read-only or system, and have its `desktop.ini` contain something like

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=somePath.dll,0
```

While it would be straightforward to use `win32api.SetFileAttributes(dirpath, win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY)` and create the `desktop.ini` from scratch, I'd like to preserve other customizations present in a potentially existing `desktop.ini`. But should I use [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) for that or does e.g. `win32api` (or maybe `ctypes.win32`)  provide native means to do so?

Comment: (the only customization-related function I found so far is [SHSetLocalizedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762250%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Comment: Hello, as this thread is not that old, I allow myself to ask you if you have found an answer. I am currently facing the same issue.

Comment: @DrHaze unfortunately I stuck with a desktop.ini from scratch so far... maybe a small bounty on this question helps motivating someone into reporting their findings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274013/how-to-make-changes-using-configparser-in-ini-file-persistent), I managed to get something working. I hope that it will help you.

Here is my base desktop.ini file:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=somePath.dll,0

[Fruits]
Apple = Blue
Strawberry = Pink

[Vegies]
Potatoe = Green
Carrot = Orange

[RandomClassInfo]
foo = somePath.ddsll,0
```

Here is the script I use:

```
from ConfigParser import RawConfigParser

dict = {"Fruits":{"Apple":"Green", "Strawberry":"Red"},"Vegies":{"Carrot":"Orange"}  }
# Get a config object
config = RawConfigParser()
# Read the file 'desktop.ini'
config.read(r'C:\Path\To\desktop.ini')

for section in dict.keys():
    for option in dict[section]:
        try:
            # Read the value from section 'Fruit', option 'Apple'
            currentVal = config.get( section, option )
            print "Current value of " + section + " - " + option + ": " + currentVal
            # If the value is not the right one
            if currentVal != dict[section][option]:
                print "Replacing value of " + section + " - " + option + ": " + dict[section][option]
                # Then we set the value to 'Llama'
                config.set( section, option, dict[section][option])
        except:
            print "Could not find " + section + " - " + option 

# Rewrite the configuration to the .ini file
with open(r'C:\Path\To\desktop.ini', 'w') as myconfig:
    config.write(myconfig)
```

Here is the output desktop.ini file:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
iconresource = somePath.dll,0

[Fruits]
apple = Green
strawberry = Red

[Vegies]
potatoe = Green
carrot = Orange

[RandomClassInfo]
foo = somePath.ddsll,0
```

The only problem I have is that the options are loosing their first letter uppercase.

Comment: Just tested and the case-loss does not affect the behaviour of the iconresource.

Comment: I think the problem was that I tried this on a network share, but since my setup changed meanwhile, I cannot reproduce the error

Comment: the lowercase problem can be fixed by [`config.optionxform = str`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1611877/321973)

Comment: I did build a script based on this: https://github.com/zommuter/desktopini.py